# Median of each pixel of a set of images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, video, median

I would like to calculate the median of each pixel in a set of images or "video".  However, when MATLAB starts calculating this, it takes a very long time and finishes randomly with an index error.  Why?

This is the code:

```
V = VideoReader('hall_monitor.avi');

info = get(V);

M = info.Width;  
N = info.Height;  

nb_frames_bk = 5;

v_pixel = zeros([nb_frames_bk 3]);

IB=zeros([M N 3],'double');

for i=1:M
    for j=1:N          
        for k=1:nb_frames_bk
             frm=read(V,k);
             v_pixel(k,:)=frm(i,j,:);
        end
      IB(i,j,:)=median(v_pixel(:,:));
    end
end


IB=uint8(IB);

imshow(IB);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code can benefit from a lot of refactoring.  For one thing, you are **re-reading** frames when you can just read them once, store them and use them after you're done.

Secondly, iterating over all pixels to compute your median is going to be very slow.  From what it looks like in your code, for each spatial position over the first `nb_frames_bk` frames, you collect all of the RGB values within these frames and calculate the median RGB value.

Also as a minor note, you are getting a dimension exceeds error because you defined the output matrix wrong.  You defined it as `M x N` with `M` being the **width** and `N` being the **height**.  This needs to be swapped.  Remember that matrices are defined as **height** first, **width** second.  However, this is unnecessary with what I'm going to suggest for implementing this properly.

Instead of reading the frames one at a time, specify a **range** of frames.  This way, you will get a 4D matrix where the first three dimensions references an image, with the fourth dimension representing the frame number.  You can then take the median in the fourth dimension to find the median RGB value over all frames.

In other words, simply do this:

```
V = VideoReader('hall_monitor.avi');

nb_frames_bk = 5;

frms = read(V, [1 nb_frames_bk]);
IB = median(frms, 4);

imshow(IB);
```

This is much better, to the point and guaranteed to be faster.  You also don't need to obtain the width and height of each frame as it is no longer needed as we are no longer looping over each pixel.

Comment: Do note that calculating the median R, G and B values separately like this will give you an RGB value that was not present in the image. You will likely get false colors this way. Ideally you'd compute the vector median, which is one of the RGB values of the input set. This is of course a lot more expensive and probably not worth while, but I wanted to point this out.

Comment: @CrisLuengo a very good point and that's something I overlooked. Vector median is robust as the final colour will originate from the input set. I didn't go down that route as I wanted to focus on optimizing the code provided by the OP. Either way very good observation.

Comment: @rayryeng oh thank a lot it's works ! and it's a best solution, excuse me it's my first month with matlab

Comment: @KiMaN You're very welcome.  Don't worry.  The answer I wrote above comes from many years of experience in MATLAB and I was very happy to answer.  Please don't be afraid to ask more questions in your MATLAB journey.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng, I will take advantage of your generosity to understand the concept :)!
I can't imagine the matrix 4d! and how the median function browses each point of x, y of each frame in the 4D matrix?

Comment: The `median` function has a second parameter that specifies whether to evaluate the median in a particular dimension while leaving the rest of the dimensions intact.  For example, doing `median(frms, 2)` will perform the median of each row of a matrix while independently leaving the rest alone.  Therefore, think of `median(frms, 4)` as performing the median in the **time-dimension**, where at each unique spatial location in the image, we will find the median RGB colour pixel value.  It is quite difficult to imagine this conceptually, but think of the 4th dimension as time.

Comment: It's much clearer for me now, thanks again @rayryeng